# Save to camera roll from path/URL in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

How can i save a image to the camera roll from a path/URL in PhoneGap?

Ex:

```
    canvas=document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]
    ctx=canvas.getContext()

    ctx.drawRect(100,100,200,200)

    url=canvas.toDataURL()
    saveToCameraRoll(url) // Saving to camera roll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to go from a canvas to saving to the camera roll in iOS, I have written a plugin that does just that.

https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

```
canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(win, fail, 'myCanvasID');
```

Comment: is it possible to save png or jpeg