# Is there special markup for downloading video and audio in iOS?

Tags: php, ios, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making an app in ionic phonegap where I'd like to offer streaming and downloading the video and audio files for offline use.

In Desktop and Android, this is easy. All I have to do is link directly to the file and modify the header directives in php to force the download.

In iPhone/iOs, clicking the same link tries to  open the file in a player immediately and doesn't download the file. Furthermore, it doesn't actually play the file. It just loads an empty video player.

I've tried googling this and looking it up on SO, but I can only find guides for downloading and storing the file *within the app*.

Such as: [iOS - Download Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769651/ios-download-video)

But that's not what I need. I don't want to reinvent the wheel and turn my app into a file manager. I need the phone to store it natively in cameraroll or prompt the user to load the file in whatever app they normally use for offline video.

I did find a user-level guide that shows that this is possible, but it doesn't say how we can make this possible as developers:

http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/28/save-videos-from-mail-ios/

How do I mark up a video link so that iOS knows to download it locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check File Transfer Cordova plugin to see if it works on you.

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer

And here goes an example code snippet:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/example_file.mp4");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false, null
);
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry for missing "cameraroll" in your question. I believe there's no direct way to save images from your url to your Camera Roll. However there's an indirect way for this. You can possibly load your image on the HTML5 canvas in your app. After that, just save its base64 formatted data_url to your camera roll.

Check this answer for more informations: [Save to camera roll from path/URL in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075384/save-to-camera-roll-from-path-url-in-phonegap)

Comment: I strongly believe this is the perfect answer to this question.